# connecting to Access in vb6

Tags: vb6

I am trying to connect to database with password, but i m getting an Error
This is my Connection String

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Database\HMS.mdb;" _
& "Password=admin;"
```

I am Getting an Error :
Cannot Start Your Application. Workgroup Information File is Missing or Opened Exclusively by the another user.

Comment: What version of Access are you using? Can you log in to access using this username and password? Are you currently logged into Access? Does your database use its own workgroup file (.mdw)? Can you post the shortcut's target you use to open the Access database itself (right click the shortcut and choose properties)?

Comment: Access 2007. I can access using password and i m not currently logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this connection string:

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
& "Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Database\HMS.mdb;" _
& "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin;"
```

Comment: thnk hims056 got the solution